# XGBoost predict() error with multiple features

Tags: r, predict, xgboost

I cannot see how XGBoost's predict method makes predictions using more than one feature.

```
library(xgboost)
library(MASS)

sp500=data.frame(SP500)
label=sp500[,1]
lag1=sp500[-1,]
lag2=lag1[-1]
lag3=lag2[-1]
train=cbind(lag1,lag2,lag3)

model=xgboost(data=train[50:1000,],label=label[50:1000],
objective="reg:linear",booster="gbtree",nround=50)

predict(model,train[1,]) #returns an error, because it will not accept multiple columns



predict(model,t(train[1,]))
```

transposing my test set does not return an error, however this is incorrectly using the predictors because

```
predict(model,t(train[1:5,]))
```

only predicts three values instead of the expected five

So my question is, how can I make predictions with XGBoost using the same features as were used to build the model? In this example I built a model with three features, lag1, lag2, and lag3, to predict the response, return. But when attempting to make predictions using `predict`, the function behaves as if it only will use one feature, and if it uses multiple values like when I transposed the test set, it is unknown how it is making use of these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are really close... stay with me here...

```
> dim(train)
[1] 2779    3
```

ok you trained with three features.. no surprises there

when you do this

```
> predict(model,train[1,])
Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata) : 
  xgb.DMatrix: does not support to construct from  double
```

`xboost` is looking for a matrix and you gave it a vector, moving on...

```
##this works 

> predict(model,t(train[1,]))
[1] -0.09167647
> dim(t(train[1,]))
[1] 1 3
```

because you transposed a vector, which made a 1 * 3 matrix

**but THIS is messed up**

```
> predict(model, t(train[1:5,]))
[1] -0.09167647  0.31090808 -0.10482860
> dim(t(train[1:5,]))
[1] 3 5
### Xgboost used the 3 rows and the first three columns only to predict
## the transpose didn't do the same thing here
```

the error is because transposing a (column) vector and transposing a matrix are different things

**what you really want is this**

```
> predict(model,train[1:5,]) 
[1] -0.09167647  0.31090808 -0.10482860 -0.02773660  0.33554882
> dim(train[1:5,]) ## five rows of three columns
[1] 5 3
```

**ALSO**

you gotta really be careful because if you don't give it enough columns `xgboost` will recycle the columns like this...

```
 predict(model,train[1:5,1:2])
[1] -0.07803667 -0.25330877  0.10844088 -0.04510367 -0.27979547
 ## only gave it two columns and it made a prediction :)
```

Just make sure you give it a matrix with the same number of columns or all hell will break loose :)

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed